# call php function with onclick event

Tags: php, html

php_file:-

```
class class_name{
     function method1(){
         //some code
         }
     function method2(){
         //some code
         }
}
```

in html:-

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right" onclick=""></i>
```

How can i call function from php file when the icon clicked

Comment: You probably should look into AJAX for this.

Comment: 1. in onclick call a function2. in that function make an ajax request whic goes to a php file.3. in that php file include this class file.4. now in the php page create object of this included claas php file and execute function and assign it's value to a variable. return that variable to the ajax by echo or print .5 in ajax response check response and other code what you want.

Comment: Ajax is your only way if you are looking forward to us the onclick method.

Comment: @Anant can you show me some code as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jquery demo is as follows:-

abc.php:- (you can change extension to `.html` also if you are not going to use any `php` code in this file)

```
<button class="fa fa-angle-right" onclick="myFunction();">Click Me Please!</button>

<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){

     $.ajax({url: "demo_test.php", success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});
}
</script>
```

demo_test.php:-

```
<?php
include_once('def.php');

$obj = new myClass();

$result = $obj->method1();

echo $result;
?>
```

def.php:-

```
<?php
class myClass{
    function method1(){
        echo "demo";
    }
    function method2(){
        echo "demo2";
    }
}
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/clw7hu   and  http://prntscr.com/clw7sl

Note:-

All three files must be at same working location(same directory)

It's a very small and easy sample to understand what is exactly need and how it can performed. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply.i understand but what if i want switch between functions?

Comment: call any function through object and assign it's value to te variable

Answer (score -3):

You can't, you need jQuery to do this.

Example:

```
<i class="banana"></i>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".banana").click(function() {
             // write action you want to do here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is not required. Ajax is required and javascript is enough to handle ajax. Yeah, to make things easier jQuery is quite useful.

Comment: PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side. You can call PHP from JavaScript but it must be done using AJAX so it requests it from the server asynchronously after that page is already loaded.